# docker can't find file to start app after build

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose

I am using Typescript here and using `node:latest` in Docker, and I am using `docker-compose` as well, 
I always failed to run it with docker-compose, when I run `docker run` ( manual ) it was work well,

here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /home/myapp
WORKDIR /home/myapp


RUN npm i -g prisma2

ENV PATH /home/myapp/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /home/myapp/

RUN npm install

COPY . /home/myapp

RUN prisma2 lift save --name 'init'
RUN prisma2 lift up

EXPOSE 8100

RUN npm run build

RUN pwd
RUN ls
RUN ls dist

CMD node dist/server.js
```

and my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    environment:
      DB_URI: postgres://myuser:password@postgres:5555/prod
      NODE_ENV: production
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./home/edupro/:/home/myapp/
      - ./node_modules:/home/myapp/node_modules
    ports:
      - "8100:8100"

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: prod
```

when it finishes doing CMD `node /dist/server.js` ( which folder I build because I am using TYpescript ) 
it gets an error like this :
`Cannot find module '/home/edupro/dist/server.js'`

I have to try to change `volumes` in `docker-compose.yml` as well like this:

`- /home/myapp/node_modules:/home/myapp/node_modules`

or

`- ./:/home/myapp/node_modules`

but still the same. do I miss something ? or did wrong mount? 
how is the correct way to resolve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove the volume sections from your compose since that will overwrite all the files you build in your dockerfile, so delete this:

```
volumes:
      - ./home/edupro/:/home/myapp/
      - ./node_modules:/home/myapp/node_modules
```

Comment: i am trying now, loading, also, my ENV in docker-compose can't read, should i put the ENV on Dockerfile ?

Comment: you need to use build ARGs if you need them during the build stage

Comment: can u give example,  my app can't read env after it npm install also after npm install there is script where my generator read the yaml to read the ENV,

Comment: when i use env in docker-compose DB_URI: postgres://myuser:password@postgres:5555/prod

my app cant read it  because invalide url  on here `@postgres:5555`

Comment: please explain what you did in a new post , without the required info and error mesages , I can not help you . also this is a new question which require a new post